# Remove phrases That Contain Duplicate Words from a DF (Pandas, Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am merging several DF together that are matched together based on prefixes.  This works 90% of the time to create semantically correct strings but sometimes, merging in this fashion can create phrases that "loop" together.  Here is an example of what my DF looks like which will better explain what I mean:

```
Words            Words1              Words2
Big Hitter       Up and Down         A Cold Lonely Night
Snail Mail       Wood Grain Rail     Cup of Lemon Tea
....             .....               .....
French Fries     Bat Boy Bat         Small Ball Small Ball
Phone Book       Fee No Fee          Hands up Hands up
```

The bottom two examples within column 2 and 3 are what I mean when I say they "loop together" -- i.e. the string contains duplicates of the same word.

I know how to dedupe these phrases using

```
re.sub(r'\b(.+)(\s+\1\b)+', r'\1', s)
```

But I need them gone completely.  **Does anyone know how I would go about just REMOVING these strings that contain duplicate words from each column in my DF?**

So I was hoping for a DF like

```
Words            Words1              Words2
Big Hitter       Up and Down         A Cold Lonely Night
Snail Mail       Wood Grain Rail     Cup of Lemon Tea
....             .....               .....
French Fries     
Phone Book
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. How about the following:

Break-down into steps to show the idea better:

```
In [39]:

print df
          Words           Words1                 Words2
0    Big Hitter      Up and Down    A Cold Lonely Night
1    Snail Mail  Wood Grain Rail       Cup of Lemon Tea
2  French Fries      Bat Boy Bat  Small Ball Small Ball
3    Phone Book       Fee No Fee      Hands up Hands up
In [40]:

print df.applymap(lambda x: len(' '.join(set(x.split())))==len(x))
  Words Words1 Words2
0  True   True   True
1  True   True   True
2  True  False  False
3  True  False  False
In [41]:

print df.where(df.applymap(lambda x: len(' '.join(set(x.split())))==len(x)),
               '')
          Words           Words1               Words2
0    Big Hitter      Up and Down  A Cold Lonely Night
1    Snail Mail  Wood Grain Rail     Cup of Lemon Tea
2  French Fries                                      
3    Phone Book
```

We are using a `lambda` function to break each word in the dataframe into a `list`, then convert it to a `set`, which will get rid of the multiple instance of the same word. Then we  ask if the word is becoming any shorter. If it does, there must be some repeating word. That's what the `lambda` function is doing. We create a `boolean` dataframe in this step.

`df.where` part is straight forward. It looks at the `boolean` dataframe we just created, if the cell is `true`, the resulting dataframe will get the corresponding value from `df`, otherwise the cell will get the value specified by the second argument. Here we use `''`, which will make the cells empty wherever it is `false` in the `boolean` dataframe.

Comment: Hi CT -- I keep getting this error: AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index Words')  Any Idea?

Comment: Look like not all of your columns are `string`s?

Comment: figured it out and the solution works -- would  you mind going into a little more description about HOW it works so I can learn?  Thank you!

Comment: That's actually very interesting and some great out of the box thinking, thank you!  Quick question: if I remove the ' ' portion of the script, will it delete cell as opposed to just adding a space?

Comment: The dataframe is always going to be a n*m 2D matrix if you think it that way. So the cells will still be there (i.e., not deleted such that the allocated memory is freed). However, I believe the default of the second parameter is `other=nan`. So, skipping it will probably set those cells to missing values.

Comment: Hi CT -- so a bit of a problem/update that I am struggling with here.  This solution works..sorta.  I tried to apply this solution to my larger data frame and at first glance it worked wonders, but now taking a closer look there are several instances of "looped phrases" that slipped through the cracks.  Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Hi, by 'looped phrases' do you mean things like `'looploop'`? i.e, multiple `'loop'`s but not separated by spaces?